# Where is the logout link on Super User?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Where is the logout link on Super User?

I read it is in the user profile but I can't see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on the grey drop-down arrow next to your name, and then the "logout" link.

[image]

Comment: but, seriously, we're like the Hotel California. You can check out at any time...but you can never leave.

Comment: yeah, logging out is far more difficult than it ought to be...